# Need a closed form for Fourier coefficients (if it exists)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a set of $53$ Fourier coefficients. The dc term is $0$. The $26$ positive frequency amplitudes (coefficients) are given below. The $26$ negative frequency amplitudes are the same.

$\{0.014451, 0.0095385, 0.0111566, 0.0323018, 0.0234022, 0.0104497, 0.0097798, 0.0168872, 0.0797642, 0.012786, 0.0094381, 0.012149, 0.0533323, 0.0185514, 0.0099585, 0.0101803, 0.02066, 0.040164, 0.0116112, 0.0094714, 0.0135438, 0.1592482, 0.0155471, 0.0096407, 0.0107726, 0.0270934\}$.

The values should be accurate up to the fourth or fifth decimal place.

Can anyone give me a closed form expression for these amplitudes? In general there is no reason to expect a closed form for the Fourier coefficients, (especially those that are obtained using Fourier transforms and arbitrary sample rates), but I was able to get a closed form for the phase angles which leads me to believe that there might be a closed form for the amplitudes as well.

The phase angles are given by Angle[$6n+k$] = $\dfrac{\pi(53-18k-2n)}{53}$, with $0 < 6n+k < 54$. Is it possible to have a closed form for the phase angles and not for the Fourier coefficients (amplitudes)?

Looking at the data graphically it is obvious that the amplitudes don't grow like $x$ or $1/x$; the lowest value occurs at #11. The amplitudes look more like a $\cot$ or $\cot^2$ function or maybe even a $\sec$ or $\csc$ function. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: plot of the 52 fourier coefficients]

Comment: It might help if you included a plot.

Comment: Yes. write $r_k \exp(i\phi_k)=(r_k \cos\phi_k,r_k \sin\phi_k)$ and plot those coefficients.  I plotted $r_k$ vs $k$ and did not see any pattern.

Comment: It would help if you gave us the original signal in closed form. Otherwise it is impossible to know the closed form of the fourier coefficients from just a numerical approximation.

Comment: The largest four distinct amplitudes are roughly $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$, $\dfrac{1}{4\pi}$, $\dfrac{1}{6\pi}$ and $\dfrac{1}{8\pi}$. But that's just a guess.

Comment: ive found a closed form. i had to first guess a curve (the sample data looked like a cot or a cosec) and then assume from the sample data that the min value #11 appears at an odd multiple of 90 degrees or close to it. #11 approximated to 1/2*53. 53 is my sample rate. the approx angle came to be around (2.5 cycles * 180 ) mod 360 = 40.9. some further refinement using the first value #1 gave me the closed form expression 1/(2*53*sin(12*180x/53)) which agrees with the data to the 3-4 the decimal digit. thanks for your comments and your suggestions.